# Magento Installation Problem

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Trying to install Magento but on the third step where the database is getting installed am getting this fatal error.......

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp

Tried changing "max_execution_time" in php.ini and restarted apache.But am unable to get this fixed.

Comment: Once you restarted apache w/ the higher execution time limit, what output did you receive?

Comment: It showed the same message, I checked phpinfo() the change i made was there.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a database host that is extremely slow to reach, or unreachable.

Make sure you are specifying a correct database server, the server is running, and that no funky firewall settings are blocking the connection attempt.